# GCM FCM migration. New GCM token past past April 11, 2019

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

It was mentioned that *Note that client SDKs and GCM tokens will continue to work indefinitely.*

It is clear that as long as the server endpoint has been upgraded to FCM, existing Android apps running GCM SDK with existing GCM token will continue to work indefinitely.

The question is:

Can new installs of existing app still generate new GCM tokens past April 11, 2019?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thanks Jennifer. Edited the post to make the question more clear.